# scala how to send unknown variables dynamically to one single method

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two variables, as below in each variable will have the same number of elements. in this case my variable 1 and 2 contains 3 elements.

```
val myVar  = List(first,second,third)
val mySecondVar  = List(one,two,three)
```

Now i have to call a method based on the number of elements here since my variable1(myvar) contains 3 values hence i need to call my method 3 times it may increase also. However the condition is when i call method first time input parameter to the method should be first element of first variable and first element of second variable for the first call 3rd parameter will be passed as df(data from csv file). after reading the data from csv file data will be filtered based on first and second parameter the result should be passed to second iteration in 3rd parameter.

Second iteration: First parameter to the method will be second element from variable 1 and second parameter will be second element from variable 2 and now the third parameter should contain the result of first iteration. will do some logic again will store the data in one variable the result should be passed to third iteration.

```
val input = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "false").csv("matching.csv")
var result = method(first,one,input)
var result2 = method(second,two,result)
var result3 = method(third,three,result2)

def(myvar : Any,mySecondVar : Any,input : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) : 
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame={
//some logic
return "result"
}
```

Comment: "the number of elements" means the index of element in list?

Comment: for both myVar and mySecondVar numberof  elements are same ex:if first variable we have 2 element second variable also will get same number of elements

Comment: Question is not clear, what is your input? what is the list value type. ? etc.

Comment: @Rumesh krish added and provided little more information kindly let me know if this helped you to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you want a recursive function to repeatedly step through the elements in the lists.

Calling code:

```
val csvData: OutputType = getCsvFileData()
val result: OutputType = myMethod(myVar, mySecondVar, csvData)
```

Recursive function:

```
def myRecursiveMethod(list1: List[String], list2: List[String], input: OutputType): OutputType = {
  val ongoingResult = doCalculation(list1.head, list2.head, input)
  if (list1.tail.nonEmpty) && (list2.tail.nonEmpty)
    myRecursiveMethod(list1.tail, list2.tail, ongoingResult)
  else
    ongoingResult
}
```

This method steps through the entries in the two lists and passes in the output from the calculation function each time, until the lists are empty.  Note that because the output of the doCalculation() function is both passed into and returned by myRecursiveMethod, it must have type OutputType before it is passed into the function the first time.